# Images loading with wrong width angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image

```
<div class="list" ng-controller="ListController">
<div class="list-item list-item-flex" ng-repeat="collaborator in collaboratorList">
    <div class="list-left list-left-flex">
            <img ng-src="images/{{collaborator.imgUrl}}" width="190px" height="190px"/>
        <div class="padded-text">
            <h1 class="collab">{{collaborator.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{collaborator.info}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-right list-right-flex">
        <a class="mail" href="mailto:{{collaborator.email}}"> {{collaborator.email}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my template for previewing collaborators with their images and info. Every time I close the browser and start it again, upon loading this template the height is normal, but the width of the images is 50.466px even though I've set the width both inline and in CSS. If I resize the window or refresh it they go back to the desired width of 190px. It would be great if someone can help me figure out why this happens.

Edit: This does not seem to happen in Firefox, it does in chrome and IE.

Edit2: I have finally found the solution. My it was a flex-box issue, I have made the image align to the left and the text to the right and all works fine now.

Comment: Perhaps try declaring their width with CSS as well as the html inline width you're using now, like style="width:190px;"

Comment: @CalebO'Leary I did try that aswell

Comment: Have you tried `ng-style="{width:'190px',height:'190px'}"`?

Comment: @LGSon just tried it, doesn't appear to work aswell